# Problems with Margin-Bottom and Padding-Bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a website for the first time. I'm trying to setup a sort of navigation bar thing on the right side, but I am unable to position it correctly. When I use margin or padding, only margin and padding work with top, right, and left. When I try to use padding-bottom or margin-bottom to try to center it better, nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated!.

This is basically the navigation bar I'm trying to emulate: http://pixelbot.ro/

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Img/icon.png" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nav">
            <h1 class="header">testheader</h1>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="navbar"><a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="navitem">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="navbar"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="navitem">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="navbar"><a href="http://www.github.com" class="navitem">GitHub</a></li>
                <li class="navbar"><a href="http://www.com" class="navitem">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

and my CSS:

```
body {

}

.header {
    color: white;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6em;
    background: #353535;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 30px; 
}

.navitem {
    margin: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to add bottom padding or margins to? `nav`? `navbar`? `navitem`?

Comment: I've been trying to do it to navbar because I want each list item to be raised up a bit so it's more centered. However, padding/margin-bottom hasn't been working with nav or navitem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HFBsm/2/)**

- Don't keep your `.header` class block element (div is by default set to `display:block`), it forces other elements to fall down change it to `display:inline-block` this way it wont take full width.
- use `margin-bottom:` & `margin-top:` property to set margins & note that equal margins on top and bottom element will not result the element to be in exact center because usually font line-height is more from bottom then from top.

CSS:

```
.header {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #353535;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
}
.navbar {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 18px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.navitem {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Just making sure, the main problem was the fact that the header was displayed as a block right? 

Also, is there any way to make the navigation bar completely centered inside the gray area? Rather than trying out multiple different margin changes? Thanks again!

Comment: Check this **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/HFBsm/7/)** if you are familiar with table layout system you will get what i did here :)